# Unix return code changes after sleep command

Tags: shell, unix, exit-code

```
stop()
{
sh stop.sh
ret_code=$?
<1>echo ret_code is $ret_code
}

once=true
while $once
do
stop & PID=$!
<2>echo ret_code is $ret_code
sleep 2m
<3>echo ret_code is $ret_code
if [ $ret_code == 0 ]
then
break
else
kill $PID
fi
done
```

ret_code at <1> is 0

ret_code at <2> does not print

ret_code at <3> is blank

Could someone tell why the ret_code value is changed during and after the sleep command?

EDIT:

I have tried an alternative approach. It worked -

```
#! /bin/sh

once=true
while $once
do
sh stop.sh & PID=$!
sleep 2m
kill $PID
if [ $? != 0 ]
then
echo stop has completed successfully within the time limit
echo starting ...
sh start.sh
break
fi
done
```

Comment: 1) What's stop.sh on line 3?

Comment: 2) Can you adjust the echo statements to include "1.", "2." etc and include the output of the script please?

Comment: @AshBerlin It's another shell script that actually stops the services. It usually runs fine so rc is usually 0. But sometimes it gets stuck, and hence this complex way of writing a simple stop/start process

Comment: @AshBerlin the numbers aren't actually there in the code, i just added them here for readability. I haven't got access to the program at the moment, but here's what happens - after sleep, it goes to the 'else' part and tries to kill the process. Process does not exist anymore obviously. so it goes back to 'stop' and continues to loop the same way.

Comment: Is this an accurate statement: you want to run stop.sh, killing it if it hasn't completed in 2 seconds, and record its exit status in either case?

Comment: 2 minutes not seconds. Yes, and the only way i would know that it hasn't completed in 2 minutes is if it's rc is something other than zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stop`, as a background process, runs in a subshell, so the value of `ret_code` that it sets is different from the one you check in <2> and <3> (which should be identical, as its value isn't affected by the `sleep` command).

Comment: I see ! Is there any way to use the variable in the subshell then?

Comment: Ignore the previous stupid comment :) -  I could just export the variable from the subshell to use in the main shell right?